# Strange behavior while sending multiple UDP packages .NET

Tags: vb.net, udp, byte

I want to send a big image over internet using multiple UDP packages. I cut and send the image into arrays of 65 000 bytes. My picture can be split in 3 packages (2*65000 and 2805). However only the first package arrives. I know that the packages are not being lost on the "way". 
       It looks like the packages were never sent. Here's the code of the "sender":

```
Public publisher As New Sockets.UdpClient(0)
Public subscriber As New Sockets.UdpClient(2000)
Public ep As IPEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0)



Public sub send()
    publisher.Connect(TBTo.Text, TBPort.Text)
    send_image("C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\My Pictures\Sample Pictures\Blue hills.jpg")
End sub

Public Sub send_image(ByVal file_path As String)
        Dim img As Image = Image.FromFile(file_path)
        Dim bArr As Byte() = imgToByteArray(img)
        Dim buffer As Byte(), packet_size As Long
        Dim no_of_packages As Integer
        Dim max_size = bArr.Length



        no_of_packages = CInt(max_size / 65000) + 1  

        For i As Integer = 0 To no_of_packages - 1
            packet_size = IIf(CInt((max_size - i * 65000) / 65000), 65000, max_size - i * 65000) ''the maximum size of a single packet is set to 65000 and the last packet will get the remaining of bytes..

            buffer = bArr.Skip(i * 65000).Take(packet_size).ToArray
            publisher.Send(buffer, packet_size)
        Next

End Sub
```

Then in a timer I check for the incoming packets:

```
Private Sub UDP_listener_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles UDP_listener.Tick

        Try
            Dim ep As IPEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0)
            receive_image()
            Debug.Print("received")   ''executed only once

        Catch ex As Exception
            ''nothing
        End Try

End Sub

Public Sub receive_image()
        Dim rcvbytes() As Byte = subscriber.Receive(ep)   ''Only the first packet

        Dim img1 As Image = byteArrayToImage(rcvbytes)
        My.Forms.client.p2.Image = img1
End Sub
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Is the first packet received 65000 bytes? Also are you doing this over LAN or over the internet?

Comment: Yes ,I receive only one packet of 65000 bytes. It is over the lan...actually on the same pc. I've noticed that there is some kind of a limit (about 8200). I don't know why is this. It seems like it is trying to send packets until this limit is reached..after that it stops..For example if I send 132000 bytes in packets of 100 bytes I will receive about 82 packets of 100 bytes each (so I only received 8200 of bytes from 132000). If I try to send the same amount of bytes but in packets of 65000 I will receive one.Why is that? - This is another account of mine